# clicklistener and longclicklistener on the same button?

Tags: android, onclick, actionlistener, phone-call, long-click

i am creating a call/dial button, when i click on that call/dial button, a call will be made based on the input that is displayed in the edittext. I managed to do that part. can you guys advise me whether i can do a longer click on that same call/dial button, so that a toast can come out to ask user to choose something else??

I did some research on "setOnLongClickListener" but i am not sure if i can combine it in the same call/dial button? I have attached on the working dial function which i managed to do, wondering if the "setOnLongClickListener" can be combined together somehere in the code?

```
    private void dialANumber() {

    try {
        buttonCall = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        buttonCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (display != null) {
                    Intent callNumber = new Intent();
                    callNumber
                            .setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callNumber.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + display.getText()));
                    startActivity(callNumber);
                }
            }
        });

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        Log.e("DialANumber", "Dialing the number failed", anfe);

    }
```

this code is working. i hope a longer click can be made on the same call/dial button so the button can have a normal click to make a call, and longer click to pop out a toast. Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes i did.. i change the button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.call); into buttonCall = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

Answer (score 8):

Note that returning "false" on the long click listener will have the UI responding to the long click as a short click too. Return "true" if you want to kill that off. "True" means "yes, I used this event" and "false" means "whether I used it or not, the environment is free to respond as well." (I know this because I just used AkashG's answer in my own app.)

Comment: Point to be noted "Note that returning "false" on the long click listener will have the UI responding to the long click as a short click too". Have been struggling since 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this:

XML file:

```
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/call"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CALL"/>

    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/callBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
```

For button click event:

```
        Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.call);
        button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Long CLick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {


             if (display != null) {
                Intent callNumber = new Intent();
                callNumber
                        .setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callNumber.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + display.getText()));
                startActivity(callNumber);
            }
            }
        });
```

For imageButton:

```
        ImageButton imageButton=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.callBtn);
```

imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
            public void onClick(View v) {
            if(check==false){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "CLick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        imageButton.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                check=true;
            if(check){
                Log.d("bool", check+"");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Long CLick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                check=false;
            }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Declare this at the top(golbally):

```
boolean check=false;
```

Comment: hi thanks.. i've tried but the setOnLongClickListener prompt for 3 fixes: Change to setOnClickListener(..)' ,  change to setOnKeyListener(..)' and change to setOnTouchListener(..)' ...

Comment: i think you must be declaring imageButton in xml file.change it to only button,it wont ask you to fix then.i implemented it and is working fine.

Comment: i change the button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.call); into buttonCall = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2); as i did my call button to be imageButton as i making it an image.. does setOnLongclickListener cannot work on imageButton?

Comment: setOnLongclickListener also works on imageButton.after replying to your comment i made an attempt to do with imageButton and did it successfully.if you want i can post that too.

Comment: Hi mate, the toast pop out after i long click but immediately after that, a call is made... i think after the setOnLongClickListener funtion is done, the setOnClickListener does its job, which i dont want..

Comment: can u maintain this through boolean variable??

Comment: sorry mate i dont understand what u mean.. my apologies.. i'm still new in JAVA..

Comment: Try the sample code in the blog:http://androidimran.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-timertask-example.html. You have to tackle with onTouchListener,get the value of counter.if its value is greater or equal to 2-3 than call long click listener otherwise click listener of button.

Comment: Changes done only for the imageButton.Its upto you whether to use button or imageButton code remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

A GestureDetector with a SimpleOnGestureListener would help you differentiate between the different types of presses.  A GestureDectector is a class which can read different types of touch events (for example, single taps and long presses), and sends them to a listener which handles each type differently.  Here's the documentation on the Detector and Listener.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html

First, set up your SimpleOnGestureListener, the important methods for you to override will be `onSingleTapUp` and `onLongPress`.  In your `onCreate`, create an instance of GestureDetector that references your listener.  Then, attach an `OnTouchListener` to your button that sends the event to your detector.  You'll want it to look something like this:

```
//Set up the Detector
GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener myGestureListener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)
    {
        //Your onClick code
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e)
    {
        //Your LongPress code
        super.onLongPress(e);  
    }
};

//And make a variable for your GestureDetector
GestureDetector myGestureDetector;

...

@Override
onCreate(Bundle b)
{
    ...
    myGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(myActivity.this, myGestureListener);
    ...
}

...

//And finally, wherever you are setting up your button
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
    {
         myGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
         return false;
    }
```

There a a bunch of other types of events this class can interpret in case you want to get even more fancy. GestureDetector is a very good class to do a little research on, it can be very useful and isn't too complex.  Hope this helps.

Comment: hi there thanks i will try real soon.. my laptop just crashed few days back.. :-(