# How to listen onTouch and onClick event simultaneously?

Tags: android

I have a button and a text label displaying a number. I want to click the button to add the number of the label to the button. I want to also enable holding on the button for a while and later start to add the number continuously. If the longclick event has added the number, the click event will do nothing. How can I implement this?

Comment: look into [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11374444/3326331)

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom `TouchListener` like this (this is very basic, written in the browser, not in an IDE):

```
boolean touching = false;
long startTime = 0;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {

switch (e.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    if(touching){
        onLongClick(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)
    }else{
        touching = true;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis;
        onClick();
    }
    break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
       touching = false;
    break;
   }
return true;
}

onLongClick(long elapsedTime){
//Do stuff
}
```

Comment: I think you could use e.getDownTime() instead of startTime, but I'm just reading it on the doc, never actually used.

Comment: which function is this onLongClick? The parameter you passed is time interval. Any way, I think you code under if(touching) else{..} will never be called cause a action_up must be followed by a action_down event.

Comment: ACTION_DOWN will be called several times if you hold down your finger. ACTION_UP/CANCEL will be called when you lift your finger.
onLongClick(long) is a method that you implement, you will have an elapsed time to know for how long the button was pressed.